# How to do dependency injection in C?

Tags: c, dependency-injection

I'm looking for a good technical solution to doing DI in C.

I have seen some of the DI questions here already, but I haven't seen one with any actual examples or concrete implementation suggestions.

So, lets say we have the following situation:

We have a set of modules in c; we want to refactor those modules so that we can use DI to run  unit tests and so on.

Each module effectively consists of a set of c functions:

module_function(...);

Modules depend on each other. Ie. Typically you may have a call such as:

```
int module1_doit(int x) {
  int y = module2_dosomethingelse(x);
  y += 2;
  return(y);
}
```

What is the correct approach to DI for this?

Possible solutions seem to be:

- (1) Using function pointers for all module functions, and when invoking a function do this (or similar):

  int y = modules->module2->dosomethingelse(x);
- (2) Compile multiple libraries (mock, std, etc.) of with the same symbols and dynamically link in the correct implementation.

(2) seems to be the correct way of doing it, but is difficult to configure and annoyingly forces you to build multiple binaries for each unit test.

(1) Seems like it might work, but at some point your DI controller is going to get stuck in a situation where you need to dynamically invoke a generic factory function (void *(* factory) (...) say) with a number of other modules that need to be injected at runtime?

Is there another, better way of doing this in c?

What's the 'right' way of doing it?

Comment: there's really no good answer to your question. What you're trying to do doesn't make much sense in C. "You're doing it wrong" or "choose a different language" isn't much of an answer. I'm not trying to annoy you, but I'm trying to say that you're demanding something of C that really doesn't play to its strengths.

Comment: Look at the linux kernel. E.g. every driver is a module that implements a specific interface (depending on which driver type it is). All modules are loosely coupled, and depending on the specific configuration of the machine the kernel is running on, modules (/dependencies) are wired together runtime. This is performed by each driver module filling out a struct of function pointers (the interface), the struct is then provided to the dependent module dynamically. Is is actually pretty nicely structured. :)

Comment: Could not disagree more with @RafeKettler - DI is a software engineering best practice which has surfaced as an important coding style, particularly in the last 10 years. This OP is simply trying to apply a "new" best practice to a language that has been around for a **long** time, and there's absolutely nothing wrong with that.

Comment: @RafeKettler Because programs have become too big for idiomatic C (and thus for C, one might argue).

Comment: @RafeKettler  We just don't really know how anymore, I'm being serious, and the code bases people say "look at X" about are always horrific examples.

Comment: @BjarkeFreund-Hansen does [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/169746/37254) code look the way you mentioned about drivers in linux kernel?

Comment: @overexchange: I get a 404 error trying to load the page you just linked.

Comment: @BjarkeFreund-Hansen Query migrated [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/354298/image-processing-dependency-injection). Let me delete, my previous comment

Comment: My advice is to go with option (2), see an answer below

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I've concluded that there is no 'right' way of doing this in C. It's always going to be more difficult and tedious than in other languages. I think it's important, however, not to obfuscate your code for the sake of unit tests, though. Making everything a function pointer in C may sound good, but I think it just makes the code horrific to debug in the end.

My latest approach has been to keep things simple. I don't change any code in C modules other than a small `#ifdef UNIT_TESTING` at the top of a file for externing and memory allocation tracking. I then take the module and compile it with all dependencies removed so that it fails link. Once I've reviewed the unresolved symbols to make sure they are what I want, I run a script that parses these dependencies and generates stub prototypes for all the symbols. These all get dumped in the unit test file. YMMV depending on how complex your external dependencies are.

If I need to mock a dependency in one instance, use the real one in another, or stub it in yet another, then I end up with three unit test modules for the one module under test. Having multiple binaries may not be ideal, but it's the only real option with C. They all get run at the same time, though, so it's not really a problem for me.

Comment: +1 for multiple binaries. That really does seem to be the only reason solution.

Comment: Can you factor out a dependency to a separate `dependency.h` file,
then configure the build system to use `real_dependency.cc` for production code and `test_dependency.cc` for testing code?

Answer (score 17):

I don't see any problem with using DI in C.  See:

http://devmethodologies.blogspot.com/2012/07/dependency-injection.html

Comment: That's a good post on the topic. Function pointers do seem like a good approach; you just have to be aware that without link-time optimization you take a bit of a performance hit for using them (compared to ABI approach of linking in or dynamically loading a single specific instance of the symbols you need to use).

Answer (score 9):

This is a perfect use-case for [Ceedling](https://www.throwtheswitch.org/ceedling).

Ceedling is sort umbrella project that brings together (among other things) Unity and CMock, which together can automate a lot of the work you're describing.

In general Ceedling/Unity/CMock are a set of ruby scripts that scan through your code and auto-generate mocks based on your module header files, as well as test runners that find all the tests and makes runners that will run them.

A separate test runner binary is generated for each test suite, linking in the appropriate mock and real implementations as you request in your test suite implementation.

I was initially hesitant to bring in ruby as a dependency to our build system for testing, and it seemed like a lot of complexity and magic, but after trying it out and writing some tests using the auto-generated mocking code I was hooked.

Answer (score 3):

A little late to the party on this but this has been a recent topic where I work.

The two main ways that I've seen it done is using function pointers, or moving all dependencies to a specific C file.

A good example of the later is FATFS.
http://elm-chan.org/fsw/ff/en/appnote.html

The author of fatfs provides the bulk of the library functions and relegates certain specific dependencies for the user of the library to write (e.g. serial peripheral interface functions).

Function pointers are another useful tool, and using typedefs help to keep the code from getting too ugly.

Here's some simplified snippets from my Analog to Digital Converter (ADC) code:

```
typedef void (*adc_callback_t)(void);

bool ADC_CallBackSet(adc_callback_t callBack)
{
    bool err = false;
    if (NULL == ADC_callBack)
    {
        ADC_callBack = callBack;
    }
    else
    {
        err = true;
    }
    return err;
}

// When the ADC data is ready, this interrupt gets called
bool ADC_ISR(void)
{
    // Clear the ADC interrupt flag
    ADIF = 0;

    // Call the callback function if set
    if (NULL != ADC_callBack)
    {
        ADC_callBack();
    }

    return true; // handled
}

// Elsewhere
void FOO_Initialize(void)
{
    ADC_CallBackSet(FOO_AdcCallback);
    // Initialize other FOO stuff
}

void FOO_AdcCallback(void)
{
    ADC_RESULT_T rawSample = ADC_ResultGet();
    FOO_globalVar += rawSample;
}
```

Foo's interrupt behavior is now injected into the ADC's interrupt service routine.

You can take it a step further and pass a function pointer into FOO_Initialize so all dependency issues are managed by the application.

```
//dependency_injection.h
typedef void (*DI_Callback)(void)
typedef bool (*DI_CallbackSetter)(DI_Callback)

// foo.c
bool FOO_Initialize(DI_CallbackSetter CallbackSet)
{
    bool err = CallbackSet(FOO_AdcCallback);
    // Initialize other FOO stuff
    return err;
}
```

Comment: But in this case ADC interrupt is blocked till callback function is called. If call back itself calls another callbacks it would make ISR longer.

Comment: Like anything, it's a tool.  Using it poorly will give you poor results.  Chaining callbacks, however, is not a problem I've seen in anyone's embedded code so far.  Usually the opposite is the problem.

Comment: This is a good technique, you just have to be aware in case you are dealing with ISR callbacks to keep the implementation as short and efficient as possible. If you need to do a lot of stuff based on that ISR execution, just use a flag, or another function pointer, or a message (in case of an RTOS), or whatever, to handle that outside of the ISR.

Comment: @RyanB Why wasn't `ADC_callback` declared before the line `if (NULL == ADC_callBack)`?

Comment: @MehdiCharife It's an incomplete code snippet.  I may have simply forgotten to include that line in the snippet, or assumed it wasn't important to the point.  I hadn't run this through a compiler at that time.  But yes, you are right that we must declare `ADC_callback` before use in the if statement or elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

There are two approaches that you can use. Whether you really want to or not, as Rafe is pointing out, are up to you.

First: Create the "dynamically" injected method in a static library. Link against the library and simply substitute it during tests. Voila, the method is replaced.

Second: Simply provide compile-time replacements based on preprocessing:

```
#ifndef YOUR_FLAG

    /* normal method versions */

#else

    /* changed method versions */

#endif

/* methods that have no substitute */
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how dependency injection could be done in C (basically the option (2) OP mentioned):

```
// person.h file
struct Person {
    char birthday[sizeof("YYYY-MM-DD")];
};
int get_age(const Person *person);

// person.cc file
#include "person.h"
#include "get_todays_date.h" // we import get_todays_date() dependency

int get_age(const Person *person) { 
    char *today = get_todays_date();
    return compute_difference(today, person->birthday);
}
```

If `get_todays_date()` is executed in a production environment, it should always return the accurate date.

If `get_todays_date()` is executed in a test environment, we make it
return a fixed date, so that the following test could be written:

```
// person_test.cc file
#include "get_todays_date.h"

const char today[] = "2020-01-06";
char* get_todays_date(void) { return today; } 

int main() {
    Person person = {.birthday = "2000-01-05"};
    assert(get_age(&person) == 20); // our test
    return 0;
}
```

`get_todays_date` is a dependency for `person.h` file

When you compile the code for production environment, link the translation unit including the real implementation for `get_todays_date()` (~i.e. include `get_todays_date.cc` file into the compilation process)

When you compile the code for testing, do not link the translation unit corresponding to `get_todays_date.cc`